# Nlog set Database target programatically and access custom log message properties

Tags: database, arguments, config, nlog

I need to support database logging. 
For that I decided to use nlog because it brings database support.
But first of all I need to setup the configuration programatically.
As far as I understood it I have to set the layout for the target.
But the class "DatabaseTarget" does not have any property related to Layout :/.

```
                        var dbTarget = new DatabaseTarget();
                    dbTarget.ConnectionString = LogConnectionString;
                    dbTarget.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    dbTarget.CommandText = "exec dbo.InsertLog @level=${level}, @callSite=${callsite}, @message=${message}, @stackTrace=${stacktrace}, @machinename=${machinename}, @processname=${processname}";
```

Is the layout definition really necessary for the DatabaseTarget. If so how do I set it programatically?

Additionally I want to pass some information. But I am not sure how I can assign those informations for the procedure. 
As far as I understood it I can assign those variables:
https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layout-Renderers

But NLog support generic arguments with his Log Method. It looks like this:

```
_nLog.Log<AJourFaultLevel>(ConvertLogLevel(logEntry.Level), logEntry.Message, logEntry.Fault);
```

How can I assign the passed "logEntry.Fault" value for my stored procedure?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current log-statement injects logEntry.Fault as parameter into `string.Format(logEntry.Message, logEntry.Fault)`:

```
_nLog.Log<AJourFaultLevel>(ConvertLogLevel(logEntry.Level), logEntry.Message, logEntry.Fault);
```

If you are using NLog 4.5 then you can use [structured-logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging) where you can name the parameter like this:

```
_nLog.Log<AJourFaultLevel>(ConvertLogLevel(logEntry.Level), "Fault occurred: {AJourFaultLevel}", logEntry.Fault);
```

Then you can access the named parameter using `${event-properties:item=}`:

```
dbTarget.CommandText = "exec dbo.InsertLog @level=${level}, @callSite=${callsite}, @message=${message}, @stackTrace=${stacktrace}, @machinename=${machinename}, @processname=${processname}, @faultLevel=${event-properties:item=AJourFaultLevel}";
```